# How to call a async await method from a CLR C++

Tags: c#, visual-c++, async-await, managed-c++

I have a C# library with the following code:

```
    namespace MyProducer
    {
        public class Producer
        {
            public async Task PublishAsync(int Id, string name)
            {
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I call this from a managed CLR C++?